# how to set a cookie in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies

I want to add a cookie so that I can exclude my interaction with my website from google analytics (I don't have access to put files on server as is third party application)

Is it possible to set a cookie with javascript by executing code in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: I believe you can also exclude your own IP address in the Google Analytics interface.

Comment: This Analytics help page shows you how to filter out your own IP from the reports: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481

Answer (score 9):

```
javascript:document.cookie="name=value"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, what you mean is:

```
javascript:void(document.cookie="cookiename=value");
```

Hope this could help you.

**Update:**

For new browser version you have to also enable javascript to be executed in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use firebug on explorer or the js console in ie8.
just type document.cookie="XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug";

then you can verify it was set by typing 
document.cookie

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if pure JavaScript can do that but i use simple PHP code to do that :

```
if (isset($request->get['tracking']) && !isset($request->cookie['tracking'])) {
    setcookie('tracking', $request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000, '/');
}
```

put it in your index.php to save cookie when page loads - if i get your purpose correctly .

*because you want addressee bar , it is better to use PHP and Get request .

Hope it help .

Comment: How this could help if the OP clearly stated "I don't have access to put files on server". He might not be even using PHP.

Answer (score -3):

Yes its possible to change cookie values, or to create new cookies from the address bar. I am not so good with javascript, but this should help you change cookie values:

```
javascript:alert(window.c=function a(n,v,nv) {c=document.cookie;c=c.substring(c.indexOf(n) +n.length,c.length);c= c.substring(1,((c.indexOf(";")>-1) ?  c.indexOf(";") : c.length)); nc=unescape(c).replace(v,nv); document.cookie= n+"="+escape(nc);return unescape(document.cookie);}); alert(c(prompt("cookie name:",""), prompt("replace this value:",""), prompt("with::","")));
```

And this, to create new cookies

```
 javascript:document.cookie = cookieName + '=; expires=3600;' +"path=/; domain=" +
                    window.location.hostname;
```